# why is javascript incrementing my number?

Tags: javascript

```
<span id="9460116557269599" onclick="getdata(6557269599,9460116557269599)"> More...</span>

function getdata(tn,x){
alert(x); 
}
```

Why is 9460116557269600 received as x.

It should be 9460116557269599.

Comment: There is no jquery here.

Comment: Two different functions: getdata vs geth20

Comment: This may have something to do with the length of the number ? what OS and browser are you using ?

Comment: Anton Kovalenko got it right!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All numbers in JavaScript are floats, and 9460116557269599.0==9460116557269600.0.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling function `getdata`, whereas the function code you've shown us is for `geth20`, so clearly the code is altered in the function `getdata`.

edit: now that you've edited the code, Anton Kovalenko's answer is definitely correct.

Comment: sorry i edited my question to the proper code

Comment: +1 for honesty and effort!- thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`geth20` should be `getdata`

[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/uqazok/1/edit)

```
function getdata(tn,x){
   alert(x);    // 9460116557269599
}
```